# Batch file called from .Net doesn't run

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file from my Vb.Net application. VS 2010 targetting .Net 4.

It works fine under Windows XP.

Under Windows 8, I get the UAC prompt as expected, and I see the command window appear briefly, but it disappears immediately, and none of the commands in the batch file appear to be executed.

I have tried replacing the batch file with a single `pause` command but the window still just disappears without waiting for input.
Here is my code:

```
    processStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    processStartInfo.FileName = Script  ' batch file name

    If My.Computer.Info.OSVersion >= "6" Then  ' Windows Vista or higher
        ' required to invoke UAC
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas"
    End If

    processStartInfo.Arguments = Join(Parameters, " ")
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = True

    process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)
```

Comment: Add "pause" to the end of the .bat file so you can read the error message.  Never forget to check the Process.ExitCode so you can diagnose complete failure.

Comment: @Hans As I stated in the question, I replaced the whole of the batch file with a single pause command, but the window just disappears immediately.
I can perhaps try looking at Process.ExitCode, but I assume as the command window is being displayed (albeit very briefly) that the process does appear to be started OK. I don't want my code to wait for the process to complete, although I could perhaps do that temporarily for debugging purposes.

Comment: If you rename the .bat so it's not found, `Process.Start` should throw a "file not found" exception. Does that happen?

Comment: Your source code snippet is completely useless for us. Where is the batch file stored, on local disk or on a server? Is the batch file called with complete path and name? Is an UNC path or a mapped network drive path used? What is the current working directory of the batch or the .NET application? Why I'm asking that? Try to run a batch file with current working directory on a server using UNC path manually and you get the answer.

Comment: Sorry, you're right I should have included the code for generation of the batch file name. I don't believe the problem is that it is not finding the file though. It is in the same directory as the main exe and the dll containing this code. I am using the full path which I get using: `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath`

Comment: In the UAC prompt that appears I can choose to display the location, and this appears to be correct (it shows the full path to cmd.exe which it appears to be invoking with /C followed by the full path of my batch file and then my arguments).
I have now tried renaming the batch file (that was a good suggestion, thanks) and I do indeed get a File Not Found exception.
My suspicion is that it is something to do with user access rights. Using the 'runas' verb seems to be sufficient to cause the prompt to be displayed.

Comment: I have done a bit more testing, and I believe the problem may be related to the arguments that I am passing to the batch file. It seems that cmd.exe does odd things when parameters are passed that contain quotes.
I think I'm onto a solution. I'll post the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The problem seems to be that cmd.exe treats its arguments differently depending on whether or not they contain quote characters. To get around this. I call cmd.exe directly instead of using ShellExecute, and I surround the whole of the command in quotes.

```
Dim script As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Test.bat"
RunCommand(script, """a quoted string""", "string2")

Private Function RunCommand(Script As String, ParamArray Parameters() As String) As Boolean

    Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
    Dim processStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Dim OK As Boolean

    processStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    processStartInfo.FileName = """" & Environment.SystemDirectory & "\cmd.exe" & """"

    If My.Computer.Info.OSVersion >= "6" Then  ' Windows Vista or higher
        ' required to invoke UAC
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas"
    End If

    processStartInfo.Arguments = "/C """"" & Script & """ " & Join(Parameters, " ") & """"
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

    'MsgBox("About to execute the following command:" & vbCrLf & processStartInfo.FileName & vbCrLf & "with parameters:" & vbCrLf & processStartInfo.Arguments)
    Try
        process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)
        OK = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Unexpected Error running update script")
        OK = False
    Finally
        If process IsNot Nothing Then
            process.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try

    Return OK

End Function
```